# How to call tab group child activity when a notification arrives in Android?

Tags: android, tabs

I am working on push notifications, getting notification in that service click on notification we generate a dialog cancel and view cancel---> finish() view-----> redirect to the tab activity. How to call the tab child activity and how to determined activity call to notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a flag in your start Intent, in your tab Activity, switch to child tab according to the flag.

Comment: hi handrenliang any example in above pattern